# Splitting field of a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, splitting-field

What is the definition of the splitting field of a $p$-group? As I was reading an article I saw this statement :

> Let $P$ be an extra special $p$-group and $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with char$(\mathbb{F})\neq p$ that is a splitting field for $P$.

At first I thought it is equivalent to say that $\mathbb{F}$ contains a primitive $|P|$th root of unity but then I realised that if $\mathbb{F}$ contains a primitive $|P|$th root of unity then char($\mathbb{F}$) cannot be equal to $p$ so the first assumption is unnecessary.

Comment: Perhaps it means that it is a splitting field for a polynomial over a smaller field, and the Galois group is $P$?

Comment: Well, I don't think so because in some other paper I also saw the statement : "Let $K$ be the splitting field of $G$ and all of its subgroups.".

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is a concept in group representation theory. See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_field